# Query all the matched values from the database based on a list of multiselect list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a multiselectlist that returns a list of values, I want to get the data from the database that maches all of the selected Ids,

For Example: if the user selected(RequestIdStatus=[1,2,3]), I want to get the data from the database where
RequestIdStatus is 1,2,and 3

Here my ViewModel:

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
   
    public string RequestCode { get; set; }

    public string RequestDate { get; set; }
    public string ComplaintIdType { get; set; }
    public string ComplaintAgainstIdType { get; set; }

    public List< WorkflowStatus> RequestIdStatus { get; set; } // النتيجة
    
}
```

My Model:

```
public class RequestModel
{
   
    public long RequestCode { get; set; }

    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime RequestExpireDate { get; set; }

    public WorkflowStatus RequestIdStatus { get; set; }
}
```

my WorkFlowStatues class;

```
public enum WorkflowStatus
{
    [EnumMember]
    New = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    JusticeWritingUnderProccessing = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    JusticeWritingReply = 3,
}
```

Conrtoller:

```
public ActionResult GeneratingReports(ReportViewModel Report)
{
    var RequestReport = _requestServices.GetRequetsForReport().Where(c =>

      c.RequestIdStatus == Report.RequestIdStatus
    ).Select(c => new ReportViewModel
    {
        RequestCode = c.RequestCode.ToString(),
        RequestDate = DateHelper.ConvertGregorianToUmAlQura(c.RequestDate, "dd / MM / yyyy"),
        ComplaintIdType = AppCache.ComplaintTypeName(c.ComplaintIdType),
        ComplaintAgainstIdType = AppCache.ComplaintAgainstTypeName(c.ComplaintAgainstIdType),
        RequestStatus = AppCache.RequestStatusName(c.RequestIdStatus),
        RequestResult = AppCache.RequestRName(c.RequestIdResult),
        AgencyDocumentationEmployeeId = _requestServices.GetUserFullNameById(c.AgencyDocumentationEmployeeId)
    }).ToList();

    string ReportJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RequestReport);
    return Content(ReportJson);

}
```

The list of RequestIdStatus are posted correct to the controller, but I want to set the right condition to returned the data for all of the selected ids at this line:

```
 c.RequestIdStatus == Report.RequestIdStatus
```

I got this error:

```
Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type "WorkflowStatues" and "List<WorkflowStatues>"
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `c.RequestIdStatus` ?

Comment: it is enum WorkflowStatus that takes numbers 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Update your `Where` condition as below. As your `Report.RequestIdStatus` is `List<WorkflowStatus>` and `c.RequestIdStatus` is `WorkflowStatus` you can check with `.Contains`.

```
.Where(c => Report.RequestIdStatus.Contains(c.RequestIdStatus))
```

Comment: This did not work for me, it will return the data if I only selected one item from the dropdownlist